# How to assign text to object attribute

Tags: javascript, object

I will create an object which has first name attribute. I have a textbox. Text in textbox will be object's first name value.

```
alert($("#Name").val() );
personObj = { firstname: ($("#Name").val())}
```

First line gives me the name of person. But when i want to give this name to my object, it fails.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So, do you want us to guess why it fails?

Comment: try `personObj = { firstname: $("#Name").val()}`

Comment: Your snippet worked for me ([see js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCJby/)). Maybe a little bit more code will make your issue clearer.

Comment: it fails again, i think that it is not related with bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/agX3w/) for me...

```
personObj = { firstname: $("#Name").val()}; //External parenthesis are not required... and don't forget the trailing semicolon
alert (personObj.firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a valid code and should also work without any problem